# Angular2 routes

Tags: angular, routes

I'm currently working on an Angular 2 project and even though everything concernig routes seems to be working relatively fine, I'm not entirely happy with how I've accomplished this.

Here's a diagram closely matching the structure I'm using for our app:
[image: diagram]

So, this app has two parts. According to their actions, they might require the user to be or not authenticated in order to reach them. Gaining access to one of them prevents the access to the other.

- The non-authenticated pages (painted red on the diagram) all share the same design; apart from their forms and actions, they all look pretty much the same. So I've created a template and added a `<router-outlet>` to inject the required parts.
- The authenticated pages all share the same structure: a navbar and a `<router-outlet>` to inject their contents; So, they all share the same parent: `LayoutComponent` (which belongs to `LayoutModule`).

As you can see from the diagram, there are some particularities about each page: some redirect, some are not accessible and some of them do not have a path. The only way I was able to achieve this setup was by setting all the routes on the `LayoutModule` and even then, I was not to able to cover all of the cases (particularly the redirect from the root to `/home`).
Also, `/page3` and `/page4` are not accessible, but each have their own component because they have links to reach the children which are injected via a `<router-outlet>`.

Since every page has its own module (and the subpages are contained in them), I'd like to be able to set the routes in each module, to keep everything tight to each module and not spread around the app's code.

Here are the routes defined on the LayoutModule, later imported via `RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)`:

```
let ROUTES: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: LayoutComponent,
  children: [
    {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
    }, {
    path: 'page2',
    component: Page2Component
    }, {
    path: 'page3',
    component: Page3Component,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      component: Subpage31Component
      }, {
      path: ':id',
      component: Subpage32Component
      }, {
      path: 'subpage3',
      component: Subpage33Component
      }
    ]
    }, {
    path: 'page4',
    component: Page4Component,
    children: [{
      path: ':id/subpage1',
      component: Subpage41Component
      }, {
      path: ':id/subpage2',
      component: Subpage42Component
      }]
    }
  ]
}];
```

Is it possible to define the routes in each module?
I'm sorry for such a verbose post but I'm trying to provide as much insight about my problem, as I can.

I'm using Angular 2.2.0 and using angular-router 3.2.0.

Comment: Have you checked this documentation [ROUTING & NAVIGATION](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html), it goes in deep to discuss separating Routes in the Module based on feature, they also talk about lazy loaded routes. Also look at this [Plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/eplnkr.html), Hope this helps!!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your comment and reference. It was really helpful. I ended up making use of a few things from the link (and learned quite a lot from it as well. Anyway, I managed to solve the problem. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the links provided by other users, I was able to cook up a solution for my problem. As I mentioned, my application has two parts with different settings for authenticated and non-authenticated users. For the non-authenticated part, I set up a module with it's own routes and `router-outlet` (for nested content).

For the authenticated part (since, among other things, it shared a navbar and a `router-outlet` across all the pages, I've created a `LayoutModule`, and defined its routing module as follow:

```
// import section

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: LayoutComponent,
  children: [
    ...Page1RoutingModule.routes,
    ...Page2RoutingModule.routes
    // and so on
  ]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule {
}
```

Where `routes` is a public variable for each routing module, like this:

```
// imports

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'page1',
  component: Page1Component
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Page1RoutingModule {

  public static routes = routes;
}
```

I have not included the authentication guards for simplicity sake, but this way, they can be configured globally on the LayoutRoutingModule, or easily on each module (if for some reason, custom rules are needed for accessing them).

Hope this helps anyone facing the same issue I had.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it possible to define routes within children modules, it's the recommended approach because it results in cleaner and more maintainable code.  See the [routing and navigation docs on angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#child-routing-component).  The entire guide builds up a hello-world style app with routing, of which Child Route Configuration addresses what it sounds like you are trying to do

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I was able to get something to work based on it. Please check my answer.